# Não estou conseguindo utilizar um módulo

Tags: angular

Ocorre que estou tentando utilizar um módulo e não estou conseguindo da esse erro abaixo:

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'BordaCreateComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation. at syntaxError
```

Meu App.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { UsuarioRoutingModule } from './usuario/usuario-routing.module';
import { UsuarioModule } from './usuario/usuario.module';
import { UsuarioLoginComponent } from './usuario/usuario-login/usuario-login.component';

import { BordaCreateComponent } from './borda/borda-create/borda-create.component';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    BordaCreateComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    AppComponent,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Meu Borda.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AppModule } from '../app.module';
import { BordaRoutingModule } from './borda-routing.module';
import { BordaListComponent } from './borda-list/borda-list.component';
import { BordaCreateComponent } from './borda-create/borda-create.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BordaRoutingModule,
    AppModule
   ],
  exports: [
    BordaCreateComponent,
    BordaListComponent
   ],
  declarations: [BordaCreateComponent, BordaListComponent]
})
export class BordaModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro do `NgModule.imports`, você pode listar somente módulos, e não componentes:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    BordaCreateComponent // <----- errado
]
```

Remova a referência `BordaCreateComponente` e referencie o módulo `BordaModulo`. Adicionalmente, leia sobre o que deve ser importado no [NgModules FAQ](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-should-i-import). Um trecho da documentação (tradução feita por mim):

> #### O que eu devo importar?
>
> Importe `NgModules` cujas classes declaráveis públicas (exportadas) você precisa fazer referência nos modelos de componentes deste módulo.

Comment: muito obrigado, era isso mesmo, estou estudando Angular e ainda não entendi direito esse negócio de módulos depois dessa ficou mais claro agora.

Comment: @EdersonCoelho considere marcar a resposta como aceita se a mesma solucionou por completo o seu problema.